# Getting the running time of Xen guest domain (RTEMS)

Tags: arm64, xen, rtems

I have an RTEMS domain (as DomU) in Xen.
I want RTEMS not to notice the time passes when it does not run on a vCPU.

For example:

`<A:rtems domain (1 sec)>   <2 sec>   <B:rtems domain (1 sec)>`

At the start of B, RTEMS thinks 1 second has passed.

`rtems_clock_get_uptime_nanoseconds` shows times that the domain was not running.
At the start of B, it shows 3 seconds.

What should I do?